# as3 / flex : how to unzip a zip file including all directories structure?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have found many libraries for Flex that handle zip/unzip.

My goal is to unzip a .zip file to hard disk, **including ALL directories structure**

Any sample available for that ?
(AIR AS3)

Comment: As worded, this isn't actually a very good question; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed

Answer (score 0):

That's only possible with Air - not in a Flex web application running in Flash Player.

Comment: yes of course: AIR only (it was obvious): I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to write the file-handling logic yourself.  Looking at the [Nochump library](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15), the included classes make it easy to read the zip to get a file list; then you can iterate through the list and write the files.